# How to do multiple dispatches in component with one set state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which has to do multiple dispatches in a componentDidMount but I want to set the state once. Is there a way to do this efficiently once for only one page render?

```js
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ fetchInProgress: true });      
        this.props.getJobs(null, null) 
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.results.response.length > 0){
                var initStart = res.results.response[0].ID;
                var initEnd = res.results.response[res.results.response.length - 1].ID;
                var newStart = initStart;
                var newEnd = initEnd;
                var snewStart = null;
                var snewEnd = null;
                var sinitStart = null;
                var sinitEnd = null;
                var filterOn = false;
                var searchOn = false;
                var pagMax = (Math.ceil(res.results.response.length / 10) > 0) ? Math.ceil(res.results.response.length) / 10 : 0;
                pagMax = pagMax + 1;
                    this.props.dispatch({ type: jobConstants.JOB_SUCCESS, newStart, newEnd, initStart, initEnd, pagMax, snewStart, snewEnd, sinitStart, sinitEnd, filterOn, searchOn});
                }   
                this.setState({
                    fetchInProgress: false,
                    panelOpen:false,
                    data: res.results.response || []
                })
            });
        this.props.getJobNames()
            .then((res) => {                
                this.setState({                    
                    jobNames: res.results.response || []
                })
            });
    }
```

The expected result is to have the page rendered once rather than twice.

Comment: Well, React batches multiple setState calls if they happen within a single render cycle. what are you trying to merge? the `jobNames` setState with the one where you set `data`? They seem to be uncorrelated, whats the issue with them being separate?

Comment: jobNames is actually for one dropdown. Data is to load specific results from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to solve this issue using Promise.all() which allows you to return one promise from multiple promises. The returned promise is an array of resolved promises in the same order as the arguments.

I'm using array destructuring to access the values in the example code, but you could just resolve to `res` and then access the values with `res[0]` and `res[1]` if you wanted.

An example of how to use this in your code might be:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ fetchInProgress: true });      
  const getJobsPromise = this.props.getJobs(null, null);
  const getJobNamesPromise = this.props.getJobNames();

  Promise.all([getJobsPromise, getJobNamesPromise])
    .then(([jobsRes, jobNamesRes]) => {
      if (jobsRes.results.response.length > 0){
      var initStart = jobsRes.results.response[0].ID;
      var initEnd = jobsRe.results.response[jobsRe.results.response.length - 1].ID;
      var newStart = initStart;
      var newEnd = initEnd;
      var snewStart = null;
      var snewEnd = null;
      var sinitStart = null;
      var sinitEnd = null;
      var filterOn = false;
      var searchOn = false;
      var pagMax = (Math.ceil(jobsRes.results.response.length / 10) > 0) ? Math.ceil(res.results.response.length) / 10 : 0;
      pagMax = pagMax + 1;
        this.props.dispatch({ type: jobConstants.JOB_SUCCESS, newStart, newEnd, initStart, initEnd, pagMax, snewStart, snewEnd, sinitStart, sinitEnd, filterOn, searchOn});
      }   
      this.setState({
        // from getJobsPromise
        fetchInProgress: false,
        panelOpen:false,
        data: res.results.response || [],
        // from getJobNamesPromise
        jobNames: jobNamesRes.results.response || [],
      });
    });
}
```

See MDN docs on Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I love this result but i am getting an error here:             .then([jobsRes, jobNamesRes] => {
                if(jobsRes.results.response.length > 0){

Comment: I tried adjusting a bit now I get this error ''jobsRes' is not defined  no-undef ''jobsRes' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: Sorry @robdigm, I had a syntax error. I edited the code with these 2 fixes:
1) I was passing 2 arguments to Promise.all() when I should have been passing a single array with 2 items.
2) I think we need to wrap the destructured response in parenthesis for the .then() callback.